# Add multiple images to canvas with C#

Tags: c#, image, windows-phone-8

Basically i am trying to make a windows phone application where one by one images can be added on the canvas but the following code doesnt seem to work

```
private void AddImage_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        PhotoChooserTask chooseImage = new PhotoChooserTask();
        chooseImage.Completed += chooseImage_Completed;
        chooseImage.Show();
    }

    public void chooseImage_Completed(object sender, PhotoResult e)
    {
        if (e.TaskResult != TaskResult.OK || e.ChosenPhoto == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        Image img = new Image();
        SelectedBitmap = new WriteableBitmap(60,60);
        img.Width = 100;
        img.Height = 100;
        img.Name = "img";
        SelectedBitmap.SetSource(e.ChosenPhoto);

        img.Source = SelectedBitmap;
        e.ChosenPhoto.Position = 0;
        CollageCanvas.Children.Add(img);
        Canvas.SetTop(img,50);
        Canvas.SetLeft(img,50);
    }
```

the first time the button is clicked, image is successfully added to the canvas but when i attempt to add another image to the canvas it gives the following exception :-

**"An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Windows.ni.dll but was not handled in user code
Additional information: Value does not fall within the expected range."**

So i want to know how can i change my program to be able to add multiple images to the canvas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it has something to do with the fact that the name property of each child element has to be unique. I think this should work for you.

```
    private int index = 1;

    public void chooseImage_Completed(object sender, PhotoResult e)
    {
        if (e.TaskResult != TaskResult.OK || e.ChosenPhoto == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        Image img = new Image();
        WriteableBitmap SelectedBitmap = new WriteableBitmap(60, 60);
        img.Width = 100;
        img.Height = 100;
        img.Name = "img";
        SelectedBitmap.SetSource(e.ChosenPhoto);

        img.Source = SelectedBitmap;
        img.Name = "Photo " + index++; // Set unique name here 
        e.ChosenPhoto.Position = 0;
        CollageCanvas.Children.Add(img);
        Canvas.SetTop(img, 50);
        Canvas.SetLeft(img, 50);
    }
```

Comment: By the way, as the Canvas.SetTop and Canvas.SetLeft property are the same for each image, they will simply overlap on top of each other. You'll need to make sure you iteratively change them for each new image.

Comment: That did it, the problem indeed was about the unique name.
and yes i will work on positioning them on the canvas now that the problem is solved.